# Magento Custom Module Thumbnail and Image upload fields

Tags: php, file, magento, e-commerce

I'm currently modifying an existing module from being able to upload one image to being able to upload two: one for the thumbnail, and one that will pop up whenever they click on the thumbnail. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem for me in PHP, but Magento seems to make this a little more difficult. My problem is this:

I'm creating two upload fields in Form.php:

```
$fieldset->addField('ngal_large', 'file', array(
    'name'      => 'large',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Large Image'),
    'class'     => 'large-image',
    'required'  => false,
));
```

And

```
$fieldset-->addField('ngal_image', 'image', array(
    'name'      => 'image',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Image'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
));
```

The regular image uploads fine, and is inserted into the database. On the other hand, the large image is uploaded, but is never inserted into the database. In the controller, I've added it to the $data array to be inserted, but I must be missing some step in here to get the image name inserted. All the modules I've seen so far have only allowed for one file upload. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Look, in for large image you use file input type: `$fieldset->addField('ngal_large', 'file'` but for small image you use image input type `$fieldset->addField('ngal_image', 'image'`. Why? Maybe something wrong is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't being added to the database? Perhaps the file name is being added into the database but the file itself isn't being saved. You have to specifically make sure that the controller that handles the post request actually saves the file (you can follow the steps it uses to save the other image).